# Powerbuilder get actual height of statictext

Tags: powerbuilder, static-text

I have a statictext control with width/height set to 400 and 132 respectively.  Auto height is enabled.

The text it contains is dynamic, so the height grows accordingly.

When I read the height of it using ids_1.Object.st_product.height it always returns 132.

How can I determine the actual height at runtime?

Answer (score 0):

You could use the Rowheight() method in a datawindow expression or as part of an Evaluate.

Something like

```
dw_1.Describe("Evaluate('Rowheight()', 1)")
```

where row 1 is the row in your datawindow with the variable height.

Comment: That only gives me the height of the Band, not the individual control.